# how to write timer for to() method in camel

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

In this route i wanna execute **direct:second endpoint for every interval time** after completion of **direct:first** and **direct:first should execute only once** that's why i have written from() method with timer repeatcount=1, so could anyone please help me how to resolve this issue

```
from("timer:repeatcount=1").
.to("direct:first").  
 to("direct:second").
.setBody(simple("Hello from timer at ${header.firedTime}"))
.to("stream:out");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [loop](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/loop-eip.html) and [delay](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/delay-eip.html) to simulate timer work

```java
from("timer:repeatcount=1")
    .to("direct:first")
    .to("direct:second");

from("direct:second")
    .loopDoWhile(true)        // never ending loop, check loop component for more control
        .setBody(simple("Hello from timer at ${header.firedTime}"))
        .to("stream:out")
        .delay(1000)          // delay 1s, check delay component for more control
    .end();                   // end loop
```

2. Use [controlBus](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/controlbus-component.html) to start [an inactive route](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html#Configuringroutestartuporderingandautostartup-ConfiguringwhetherarouteshouldbestartedornotinJavaDSL) of timer